# How to save my drawing in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am studying android studio and touchevent.

First, my project is like paint.

My code is here.

```
package com.example.a2_touchevent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;

import static android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.LINE;
import static android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final static int LINE = 1, CIRCLE = 2, RECTANGLE = 3;
static int curShape = LINE;
static int color = Color.BLACK;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyGraphicView(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "선 그리기"); //draw Line
    menu.add(0, 2, 0, "원 그리기"); //draw Circle
    menu.add(0, 3, 0, "사각형 그리기"); //draw Rectangle

    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("색상 변경 >> "); //Colorchange
    subMenu.add(0, 4, 0, "빨강"); //red
    subMenu.add(0, 5, 0, "초록"); //green
    subMenu.add(0, 6, 0, "파랑"); //blue

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 1:
            curShape = LINE;
            return true;
        case 2:
            curShape = CIRCLE;
            return true;
        case 3:
            curShape = RECTANGLE;
            return true;
        case 4:
            color = Color.RED;
            return true;
        case 5:
            color = Color.GREEN;
            return true;
        case 6:
            color = Color.BLUE;
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private static class MyGraphicView extends View {
    int startX = -1, startY = -1, stopX = -1, stopY = -1;
    public MyGraphicView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = (int) event.getX();
                startY = (int) event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                stopX = (int) event.getX();
                stopY = (int) event.getY();
                this.invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(color);

        switch (curShape) {
            case LINE:

                canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
                break;
            case CIRCLE:
                int radius = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(stopX - startX, 2) + Math.pow(stopY - startY, 2));
                canvas.drawCircle(startX, startY, radius, paint);
                break;
            case RECTANGLE:
                Rect rect = new Rect(startX, startY, stopX, stopY);
                canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

and result is here.

https://ibb.co/dJMxNZ4
p.s How can I post GIF file in question?

Anyway, I want to save my draw before new mouse clickevent.
the hint in my textbook, use dynamic list, but I cant use it.

first, I create myShape class

```
private static class MyShape {
    int shapeType;
    int startX, startY, stopX, stopY;
    int color;

    static List<MyShape> myshape = new ArrayList<MyShape>();
}
```

and then, how can I use this class and save my drawing?

Thanks.

Comment: Save drawing to where? Do you want to save that as an image as a file?

Comment: No, I just want to make sure there's traces of me on the screen.

Comment: like this,

https://ibb.co/K0bx9mZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a list of drawingData( data needed for drawing a shape ) and in onDraw function you can loop through them and draw. A sample implementation of your MyGraphicView may look something like the one below.

```
private static class MyGraphicView extends View {
        DrawingData currentShape = null;
        ArrayList<DrawingData> drawingData = new ArrayList<>();

        public MyGraphicView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    currentShape = new DrawingData(curShape);
                    currentShape.startX = (int) event.getX();
                    currentShape.startY = (int) event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    currentShape.stopX = (int) event.getX();
                    currentShape.stopY = (int) event.getY();
                    this.invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    currentShape.stopX = (int) event.getX();
                    currentShape.stopY = (int) event.getY();

                    drawingData.add(currentShape);
                    currentShape = null;
                    this.invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(color);

            for (DrawingData drawingDatum : drawingData) {
                drawShape(drawingDatum, canvas, paint);
            }

            if (currentShape != null) {
                drawShape(currentShape, canvas, paint);
            }

        }

        private void drawShape(DrawingData drawingDatum, Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
            switch (drawingDatum.shape) {
                case LINE:

                    canvas.drawLine(drawingDatum.startX, drawingDatum.startY, drawingDatum.stopX, drawingDatum.stopY, paint);
                    break;
                case CIRCLE:
                    int radius = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(drawingDatum.stopX - drawingDatum.startX, 2) + Math.pow(drawingDatum.stopY - drawingDatum.startY, 2));
                    canvas.drawCircle(drawingDatum.startX, drawingDatum.startY, radius, paint);
                    break;
                case RECTANGLE:
                    Rect rect = new Rect(drawingDatum.startX, drawingDatum.startY, drawingDatum.stopX, drawingDatum.stopY);
                    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static class DrawingData {

            int shape;
            int startX;
            int startY;
            int stopX;
            int stopY;

            public DrawingData(int shape) {
                this.shape = shape;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: really thanks, but when I change the color, all figures drawn up to their color now changed. This part should I do?

Comment: Yes. You can have color too as a field in drawing data. If you find the answer helpful you can accept it. Cheers.